# XQuery substring for a sequence of items

Tags: substring, max, xquery

I want to extract all values of a column from a table, determine the maximum of those values, and return that value.

This is what I tried:

```
let $abc := doc("file:///some_local_file")//AOSCAT_MetricDetail//table[@class="pretty-table"]//tr/td[13]
return <li>{ fn:max(fn:substring($abc,1,1)) }</li>
```

But fn:substring can't handle a sequence of more than one item.

So I tried this:

```
let $set_all_mbd := doc("file:///some_local_file")//AOSCAT_MetricDetail//table[@class="pretty-table"]//tr/td[13]
for $xyz in $set_all_mbd
let $abc := fn:substring($xyz,1,1)
return <li>{ fn:max($abc) }</li>
```

It returns for every row of the table though, and I want just one single value returned.

I suppose this is very simple but XQuery is new to me and can't figure out how to do it...

Comment: ...so take your second approach, and add a `max()` call wrapped around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to apply `substring` to each item in the sequence, try

```
let $abc := doc("file:///some_local_file")//AOSCAT_MetricDetail//table[@class="pretty-table"]//tr/td[13]
return <li>{ max($abc/substring(.,1,1)) }</li>
```

(untested).

If that doesn't work then you can definitely do it with an explicit `for`:

```
let $abc := doc("file:///some_local_file")//AOSCAT_MetricDetail//table[@class="pretty-table"]//tr/td[13]
return <li>{ max(for $x in $abc return substring($x,1,1)) }</li>
```

Comment: The first worked right away! Thank you! And additionally i learned that i dont need all those "fn:" =)